# Update a UILabel twice in the same method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uilabel

I'm having some trouble figuring out hot to update a UILabel twice in one action. Basically the user hits a play button to hear a sound. While the sound is playing "message 1" appears in the UILabel. When the sound is done playing "Message 2" appears in the same label. When I run this the label goes directly to "message 2".

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
UIButton *playButton;
UILabel *answerLabel;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel;
-(IBAction) play;
@end
```

.m

```
-(IBAction) play
{    
        int length = [audioPlayer duration];
        [audioPlayer play];
        answerLabel.text = @"Message 1";
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:length];
        answerLabel.text = @"Message 2";   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you implement the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol, so I assume that at some point you set the delegate of the player to `self`

If that is the case, change your play method to the following:

```
-(IBAction) play
{    
    [audioPlayer play];
    answerLabel.text = @"Message 1";
}
```

Then implement this method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    answerLabel.text = @"Message 2";
}
```

Comment: This works, I guess my mind went blank and overlooked the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying part, no need for the  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:length] part.

Answer (score 2):

An update to the UI occurs only once the UI thread is unblocked, when it sleeps it is still blocked, so the first label never appears.

What you can do is:

```
answerLabel.text = @"Message 1";
[answerLabel performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"Message 2" afterDelay:length];
```